# UTC times in Python and Javascript are off by 5 hours, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, python, datetime

I have:

```
# Python
import datetime, time
py_utc_now = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.utcnow().timetuple()))    # 1597879534

# Javascript
var js_utc_now = Math.round(new Date().getTime() / 1000);               # 1597861534


py_utc_now - js_utc_now
>>> 18000    # seconds

18000 / 60
>>> 300.0    # minutes
```

I was always taught that UTC time was always based on GMT in London, no matter what part of the world you are in. And I'm currently in the Chicago area (-5 GMT), so this makes no sense either way.

Why are my values 5 hours apart? And how can I get the exact time for each, regardless of where I am in the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Python code is taking a time that is *already* UTC, and then passing it to `mktime`, which [expects local time values](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.mktime). This effectively doubles the timezone offset, resulting in the error you're seeing.

To get the correct UTC timestamp in Python, you can use a much simpler expression:

```
int(time.time())
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was expecting. Although it raises another question...  The python docs say the epoch is platform dependent: https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#epoch    Do you know if that means someone running a mac or windows have different times than a unix/linux based one?? Or is there some better solution for me to get the best UTC time from JS and Python??? Cause I would like the same value (ignoring lag).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Date.UTC() to retrieve the UTC date in JS.

Comment: @atomNULL The getUTCDate() returns the day of the month only. Not the full date. The OP needs to use Date.UTC() and pass all parameters (from year down to millisecond) to get the UTC equivalent of the Date object.

Comment: [*Date.UTC*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) takes the same year, month, day, etc. arguments as `new Date()` and treats them as UTC, it returns a time value.

Answer (score 0):

Both `datetime` and `new Date()` derive their values from the settings of the machine they are running on. It does not matter where in the world you are.

In Python:

```
py_utc_now = datetime.now(timezone.utc)
```

In JS I suggest you use a third-party library called `dayjs`. It's super small but it gives you a lot of flexibility when working with dates and time.
Or you can use the `getUTCDate()` method.

```
var currTime = new Date();
var js_utc_now = currTime.getUTCDate();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but the problem with this is that `currTime.getUTCDate()` returns the day of the month according to UTC, not all the seconds since the epoch.